# Looping a calculation between a series of two images

Tags: numpy, for-loop

I am trying to calculate the difference between a series of two images.

The code look like this:

```
image1[0:1000]
image2[0:1000]

def error(image1, image2):
    for i in image1 and image2:
        error = np.mean((image1[i] - image2[i])**2)
        return error 

error(image1, image2)
```

I keep getting the error `arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

All I'm trying to do is calculate the difference between image1[1] and image2[1], image1[2] and image2[2]...

The end result I am looking for is an array of errors for each image1[i] and image2[i]. Is there an alternate method or can I just solve the code I already have?

Comment: what is actual shape of image1 and image2 and what is its data type?

Comment: Images that are 30 X 30. So the dimensions are (1000, 30,30)